# Where in the specification is it defined that HTML attributes can be referenced from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I always referenced element attribute values in the form `element.value`,`element.id`. I recently learned about the `getAttribute` function. I can see the definition of the `getAttribute` function, but I couldn't find a section that defined that attribute values can be referenced from JavaScript like `element.id`.

I thought it was defined by the WHATWG, so I read DOM LS [Chapter 4](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-textcontent) and HTML LS [3.2.4.1](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-textcontent) and the whole [Chapter 3](http://%20https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attributes). However, their definitions were not found. Is this a feature that is not specified in the specification and depends on the browser implementation?

Comment: `getAttributes` does not exist on a created element, did you mean `getAttribute`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute#Specification

Comment: Are you talking about the relationship of for instance Element.prototype.id and the `id` attribute of this element? If so, the former is called an IDL attribute, and each Interface may define their own. They don't all map to attributes, and definitely not all attributes do map to IDL.

Comment: @CertainPerformance : Thank you for telling me, it was a misspelling of `getAttribute`. I fixed it.

Comment: *"I always referenced element attribute values in the form* `element.value`,`element.idname`" – You’re not referencing attributes here, you’re referencing properties. Properties that may have been configured depending on attributes in the source html.

Comment: Which properties exist are part of the interface definitions for each node type. E.g. `Element`: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element

Comment: @deceze : I already know the definition of the `getAttribute` function and want to know where the` element.id` style attribute reference is defined. I will improve the question.

Comment: @Kaiido : Yes, when I searched for IDL attributes, I wanted to know what specifications the IDL attributes work with. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lennholm : Yes, from some comments, I found that I was actually reading and writing IDL attributes through properties. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FelixKling : Yes, now I read them, but I was surprised that the definition of this interface binds JS properties and HTML attributes. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It doesn't really "bind" them. Most of the time, only the initial value of the properties is taken from the HTML attributes. There might be some exceptions were they are kept in sync.

Comment: Actually I might be wrong. Maybe the default is actually to "bind" attributes. The official term is "reflect". You can read more about this here: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-reflect https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are defined in the HTML specification. For example, see [the input element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) which includes a section titled "DOM interface" which says, among other things:

> ```
> [CEReactions] attribute [TreatNullAs=EmptyString] DOMString value;
> ```

and links to the [definition of the value property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-value).

Note, however, that the `value` property **does not** map to the `value` attribute but to the current value.

Comment: "in the HTML specification" depends what we are talking about, SVGRectElement.width is defined in the [SVG specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/shapes.html#__svg__SVGRectElement__width), other specs may extend DOM APIs. HTMLMediaElement.sinkId is defined by [mediacapture-output specs](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-output/#dom-htmlmediaelement-sinkid)

Comment: Thank you for detailed examples and explanations. It just explained what I wanted to know. I found [specifications](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/) about IDL. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It's described in the DOM Living Standard under 4.9. Interface Element [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element):

Among other things, it specifies:

> element . id [ = value ]
>
> - Returns the value of element’s id content attribute. Can be set to change it.
>
> element . className [ = value ]
>
> - Returns the value of element’s class content attribute. Can be set to change it.
>
> element . classList
>
> - Allows for manipulation of element’s class content attribute as a set of whitespace-separated tokens through a DOMTokenList object.
>
> element . slot [ = value ]
>
> - Returns the value of element’s slot content attribute. Can be set to change it.

Comment: Not sure what OP really is asking for, but it seems they already "can see the definition of the getAttributes function"

Comment: They are asking about the direct accessor properties like `.className` and `.value`